# Do I need to delete development plugins before publish my app?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am just about to finally publish my ionic app on android. I was reading the ionic documentation about how to publish the app and at some point it mentions that I have to delete some unnecessary plugins that are for development before releasing the app.
My question would be, is it really necessary? I mean will it make a difference if I don't remove it?

```
 " So first, we need to generate a release build of our app, targeted at 
   each 
   platform we wish to deploy on. Before we deploy, we should take care to 
   adjust plugins needed during development that should not be in production 
   mode. For example, we probably don’t want the debug console plugin 
   enabled, 
   so we should remove it before generating the release builds:

   $ ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-console    "
```

reference: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to v1 documentation, but you have tagged `ionic4` in your question.

As you are new I'm going to assume `ionic4` is what you are really targetting.

The most up todate Android publishing docs are here:

[Android Play Store - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/publishing/play-store)

The system that v1 used was very different to modern Ionic. There may be some advanced customisations that you can make but by default, you don't need to remove plugins before you publish.

Comment: yes you are correct, I was referring to ionic v1, while i was using ionic v4. All resolved now, thanks :)

Comment: Great :) if this helped, please upvote / mark as answer. It helps me towards my ionic4 badge and also stops others from spending time coming to read stuff thats already resolved.